# MediaWiki 1.21.3 mass deletion

Tags: php, mediawiki

I want to delete almost 1700 uploads (files and documents) from my MediaWiki wiki.

MediaWiki version: 1.21.3

I cannot use the DeleteBatch extension, it's incompatible with this version.

So, how to delete these many uploads at once with reason to delete?

Answer (score 1):

If it's your own wiki, just use [the maintenance script](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:DeleteBatch.php), that has been around since forever.